# I want to scroll the images

Tags: android, layout

I want to scroll the images in such a way that the back button is not scrolled. I am trying to take the back button above the scroll view but unable to find the solution. Please help. This is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/animal_back"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:src="@drawable/back" />

<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/ant" />

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal1"
        android:src="@drawable/bat" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal2"
        android:src="@drawable/bear" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal3"
        android:src="@drawable/cheetah" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal5"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/animal1"
        android:src="@drawable/cow" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal6"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/animal2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal5"
        android:src="@drawable/donkey" />



     </RelativeLayout>    

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And now the button is going behind. Its getting hidden.

Comment: can you put demo screen how it's look like ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please review it.

Comment: isn't your problem get solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I just need to bring the back button at front position by adding this line......

```
back.bringToFront();
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Solution of your question.

**Step 1**

Take a `RelativeLayout` as parent of your `ScrollView`. And set property to left assign to your `ScrollView`.

**Step 2**

Instead of placing `ImageView` at the end of your `ScrollView`, place it at `Right Of` your `ScrollView`.

#### Solution 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/animal_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/animal_back" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I added `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/animal_back"` code. So that ImageView will be visible to right side. and ScrollView will be set to left side of ImageView.

#### Solution 2

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            ...
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The button is getting displayed behind. How can i bring it in front?

Comment: @Sherry, To take ImageView on ScrollView, second solution is useful. If you think for left and right side, first solution will help you.

Comment: yes my problem is solved. By implementing the solution 1 layout, moreover i have to add this line in my code. back.bringToFront(); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put `back button` outside from scroll view. And then adjust thier positions as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Keep outside your back button of `Scrollview`, Can you just try below code@

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/update" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/animal_back" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/animal1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/animal2"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal1"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/animal3"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal2"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/animal4"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal3"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/animal5"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/animal1"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/animal6"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/animal2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal5"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >


<ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/animal_back"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:src="@drawable/back" />

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/ant" />

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal1"
        android:src="@drawable/bat" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal2"
        android:src="@drawable/bear" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal3"
        android:src="@drawable/cheetah" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal5"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/animal1"
        android:src="@drawable/cow" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/animal6"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/animal2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animal5"
        android:src="@drawable/donkey" />


     </RelativeLayout>    

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use frameLayout for your layout. this will help you to achieve what you want. Frame Layout details you can get [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_weight="1"
                              android:weightSum="4">
                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/animal1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:minWidth="200dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ant" />

                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/animal2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:minWidth="200dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/bat" />

                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/animal3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:minWidth="200dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/bear" />

                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/animal4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:minWidth="200dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cheetah" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/animal_back"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/back" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/animal5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:minWidth="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/cow" />

                <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/animal6"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:minWidth="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/donkey" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```